# Why unbind event on image is not working

Tags: jquery

I have got a image on which i want to disable click event , so i have used unbind event as shown below

```
$('#myimage').unbind("click");
```

But could you please let me why the click event is still working ??

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myimage').unbind("click");
})

$(document).on('click', ' #myimage', function (event) {
    alert('i am called');
});
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ygbxdspc/5/

Comment: You're adding the click handler to the `document` and then try to remove it from the image itself.

Comment: you are using different techniques to bind the event, hence its not getting unbind.

Answer (score 3):

The issue in the fiddle is your code block is already running in a `document.ready` handler (due to the settings you've chosen) so the `unbind()` is called before the event is bound, hence [no event is removed](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ygbxdspc/6/).

To fix the actual problem, you need to use the delegated form of the `off()` method as you originally attached a delegated event handler using `on()`, like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).off('click', '#myimage');
    })

    $(document).on('click', '#myimage', function(event) {
        alert('i am called');
    });
</script>
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ygbxdspc/8/)

Note that in the settings of this fiddle the JS code is set to execute as 'No wrap - in `<head>`'